# How do I cast a <out Any> generics type to a specific type, so it can be run in a generics function?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a function `replaceCollection` that takes two `MongoCollection<T>` to perform a replacement.

The function declaration is as follows.

`private suspend fun <T> replaceCol(old: MongoCollection<T>, new: MongoCollection<T>, session: ClientSession)`

It works fine when I put two `MongoCollection<SameClass>` into the function. However, I have a list of collections that I would like to replace, but I cannot find way to cast the `<out Any>` to assure the compiler that they have the same type so it can be run in the generic function `replaceCol`

```
//oldCols[i] and newCols[i] always have the same generic type 
val oldCols: Array<MongoCollection<out Any>> = ...
val newCols: Array<MongoCollection<out Any>> = ...

for(i in prodCols.indices) {
    replaceCol(preProdCols[i], prodCols[i], session)
}   

/* error on the line of replaceCol
Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter T in //...
None of the following substitutions
(
MongoCollection<CapturedTypeConstructor(out Any)>,
MongoCollection<CapturedTypeConstructor(out Any)>,
ClientSession
)
(
MongoCollection<CapturedTypeConstructor(out Any)>,
MongoCollection<CapturedTypeConstructor(out Any)>,
ClientSession
)
can be applied to
(
MongoCollection<out Any>,
MongoCollection<out Any>,
ClientSession!
)
*/
```

Comment: Do you modify your `MongoCollection`s in your function? Can you rewrite it so it does not modify them? (replacing `old: MongoCollection<T>` to `old: MongoCollection<out T>` would fix the problem)

Comment: @ardenit no I don't think so. I am retrieving information from database using the `MongoCollection` Object for the `newCol` and putting information to the `oldCol`.

Comment: I dont know what exactly your structure and code looks like, but if you know the specific types of the  generic parameter T (or at least its range), you can use sealed class in your advance to group those similar classes together and make sure they all implement the sealed class which gives you the possibility to use generics like <out SealedClassName>.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **100% sure** that collections on the same indices have the same generic types, you can use unchecked cast:

```
fun <T> replaceArray(old: Array<T>, new: Array<T>) {
    old[0] = new[0]
}

fun <T> forceReplace(old: Array<T>, new: Array<*>) {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    replaceArray(old, new as Array<T>)
}

fun main() {
    val old = arrayOf<Array<out Any>>(
        arrayOf(0),
        arrayOf("!")
    )
    val new = arrayOf<Array<out Any>>(
        arrayOf(1),
        arrayOf("?")
    )
    for (i in old.indices) {
        forceReplace(old[i], new[i])
    }
}
```

But still, the best way to solve your problem is redesigning your logic so you don't need such workarounds.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't make much sense to me to define `fun <T> forceReplace(old: Array<T>, new: Array<*>)`, while the function is supposed to take two Array with the same generic types.

Comment: You don't need to change your function. `replaceArray` is defined just like your function. `forceReplace` may be private function, or you can just do unchecked cast in your loop.

Comment: What's your recommendation on a better design on store such <out Any> collections? I have ~10 oldCol and ~ 10 newCol and am expecting more later

Comment: As was suggested, you can use sealed classes if you know which types may be used as generic parameters.